# Intellij doesn't seem actually run `sbt update` for modified dependencies

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I recently updated a personal scala library that I have published to my local maven repo.  In another project which uses this library, intellij refuses to acknowledge that this new library exists.  In fact, it seems to be disregarding the contents of the `build.sbt` file altogether.  Below is my current `build.sbt` file, *with* the updated dependency package (`org.mechko.data`).

```
name := "algorithms"

organization := "org.mechko"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File(Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository")))

resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"

libraryDependencies += "org.mechko" % "data_2.10" % "1.0.1" //updated dependency
```

It seems that running `sbt update` and `sbt run` in the terminal delivers the desired result using my updated library, so the problem is entirely with intellij.  I have tried restarting intellij, and also invalidating the cache. I even tried putting incoherent garbage in my sbt file.  Nothing evokes a response when I click `refresh project`.  Any idea what might be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that you have `auto import` enabled at `Setting > Build, Execution and Deployment > Build Tools > SBT`. But then every change in `build.sbt` will trigger an `sbt update` which may not be desired.

Comment: Also... the recommended way to import a SBT project in intelliJ is to do `File > Open` then select the SBT project's root directory ( NOT the build.sbt file).

Comment: I have `auto import` disabled for that particular reason.  Usually, whenever I make a change to the `build.sbt` file, a little clickable dialog pops up in the terminal which triggers an `sbt update`.  In this case, clicking that dialog yields no result.

The project was imported into `intellij` correctly several days ago.

Comment: But then what's stopping you from manually triggering a `sbt update` whenver you want ?

Comment: If the import pop-up not showing... there should be an icon of a person wearing a hat in the lower right corner. Click on that corner and make sure that the `import popup` option is checked.

Comment: The import popup _is_ showing up.  Clicking the popup has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

My ultimate solution had three parts:

1. Uninstall and reinstall the `scala plugin` for intellij
2. Run `sbt clean` from the terminal
3. Delete the `.idea` folder in the project root and reimport the project

I tried combinations of these steps, but only when I did all three did Intellij agree to actually run the updates.